# NSTableView not displaying strings above 10 chars length

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-bindings

My question concerns a NSTableview. I work with OSX El Capitan, XCode latest version and Objective C.

In my program I'm using Cocoa bindings with an arraycontroller and I populate the table from a MySql database. Everything works fine, I mean data are properly recovered from a MySql query and the table displays the data.

The problem is that I would like my data's width to be truncated when the size of the strings is above 10 characters, instead they are not displayed at all, but in my ArrayController I have all the values I'm querying.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. I have edited your question to make it clearer, but it is still incomplete. If you want to get help you must show your code, so that people can see precisely what you are doing. So please [edit] your question and add a [mcve]. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I just realize that there is something wrong in the storage of the class objects in the arraycontroller. So it is not a problem of data length but a problem of storing the data. Sorry for that !
I found my error, in my class the properties for the NSStrings were set to weak instead of strong. So the first load in the arraycontroller was ok but then the vales were set to nil. Just one thing I don't understand is why the small strings were kept and not the longer ones ?
I will work on that subject to improve my poor knowledge.

Sorry again and take care !